# How to give preference to user defined keymaps in Intellij idea over default

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts, keymapping

I have been using VSCode for Java development for past 1 year. But now, I want to use Intellij for my work. In VSCode, I changed some shortcuts such as endOfLine to ALT+F, startOfLine to ALT+D and they are working fine. But In Intellij, I changed these commands exactly same as in my VSCode but instead of working, these shortcuts are triggering options in the top bar like File, Edit, View etc.
Is there any way by which I can give preference to my custom keymaps over default keymaps in Intellij. Please note that I want to use only ALT key with my custom keymaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable these options:

- Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Appearance & Behavior | Appearance | Enable mnemonics in menu
- Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Appearance & Behavior | Appearance | Enable mnemonics in controls

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + letter shortcuts are commonly used for mnemonics.

Comment: Hi @CrazyCoder, thanks a lot for helping me. Could you help me with other option as well. When we see multiple suggestions in Intellij, how can we move up and down in these visible suggestions with the help of custom keymaps.

Comment: @MayankKumarThakur Post another question here or contact support at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/requests/new.